# Can のろけ話 be used in a platonic sense to refer to closeness amongst female friends?

Tags: grammar

I was reading a novel where a girl is talking about her friend who is another girl and someone says uses this phrase : のろけ話

Which I know translates to mean to speak fondly of significant other, but these girls are described as being just good friends in the novel. So I was wondering, can this be used to show extreme closeness/admiration between platonic friends or is it mean to maybe imply that one person likes the other?

Comment: Just a tip: it's best to include context (quotes, pictures etc.) in the question instead of in a comment somewhere, because you want people to see that *before* they write their answers.  Also, if you do take a picture, make sure it isn't cut off so people can see all the text.  (In this case, everything worked out because broccoli was able to write a fine answer anyway, but it's always a good idea to include this in your questions directly.)

Answer (score 3):

Usually not. In that context she is most likely teasing the other that she and her friend is as "lovey-dovey" as the real lovers.

のろける means "to brag about one's lover", but people often use it too when the speaker's inner love toward the lover is unconcealed even though s/he has no such intention. This word is not really for ordinary friends.

Comment: .  Oh let me elaborate provide context

The girl isn't talking in front of her friend. She's talking about her friend to someone else. She's saying things like 'her friend is so cute" or does things in a cute manner. Her friend doesn't show any sides of liking her or act flirty with her. The person hearing said its like she is doing that

The thing is, the novel just calls them bestfriends, like it uses the term shinyu, which is what the girl explicitly calls her friend.

I myself am unsure as I know media has girls be close/call each other cute and it is not romantic.

Comment: Oh, this is the image for context: https://imgur.com/a/kvGsTAn

Comment: @ZainAlleck okay, please look at the last みたい. It means "as if" that implies she doesn't think it a real のろけ話 either way. I think my main point still unaffected. Whether the use of this word suggests that they're in a romantic relationship or not in your context is still inconclusive from linguistic interpretation.

Comment: Oh, why is it inconclusive?

Comment: Well, they are literally/expliciticly called good friends/dear friends.  A better question I guess would be, is a metaphor like this uncommon to describe close friendship among female friends

Comment: It's common in _simile_ to compare closest friends with lovers or spouses, but it'd be confusing in _metaphor_ IMO.

Comment: Oh my mistake.  I mean, specifically in a japanese context, can a simile like that be used and just be platonic? Someone said in japanese media, its not uncommon for girls to be really close but it be platonic

Comment: @ZainAlleck Yes it can.

Comment: Oh, but its not uncommon correct and what they told me is accurate?

Comment: in the context I sent, does it seem/sound platonic?

Comment: @ZainAlleck Yes, at least for the speaker at that moment.

Comment: oh what do you mean? Is it because of a question mark used there btw? And second, as I asked earlier, its not uncommon and what I mentioned of someone telling me is accurate, correct?

Comment: My previous comment "Yes, at least for the speaker at that moment." answers your "in the context I sent, does it seem/sound platonic?". I'm not sure what you mean in the rest of your comment... Can you point to which "question mark" and which "what I mentioned of someone telling me" you're talking about?

Comment: btw on the side, what is this saying:  ねじれちゃん好きなもの百合の花ということは彼女も間違いなくレズ(間違った解釈)

Comment: That'll be another question ;)